# pic32 mips assembly pipeline: branch delay slot and load delay slot

Tags: mips, pic

Since PIC32 uses MIPS 4K core, its assembly language must be affected by the pipeline effect: both branch delay slot and load delay slot.

Question is whether the delay slot is one instruction, or more instructions? I guess it depends on the details of the pipeline.

Can't find any documentation on that.

Comment: Way back it was one slot most likely, today the pipeline is likely deeper and the one slot is there for reverse compatibility of software, simply an illusion.  Unless you have access to their source code you likely are not going to really know...And in that case the NDA would prevent you from telling us.

Answer (score 1):

The 4K pipeline has an load-to-use interlock that stalls the pipeline by one clock if a load result is used by the instruction following the load instruction. (From MIPS document *MIPS32® M4K™ Processor Core Software User’s Manual, Revision 02.03*.)

Like all MIPS32 processors, the 4K implements a [branch delay slot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_delay_slot) of one instruction.

The branch delay slot is the only thing that changes how assembly code is written, though you can rearrange code to avoid triggering the load-to-use interlock in performance critical code if needed.